# How to convert string cell array to int and NaN in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I have a string cell array that contains a mix of numbers and None values. I want to convert the None into NaN and numbers into int.

```
x = {'23','3','None'}
new_x = {23,3,NaN}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try `cellfun` with `str2double`, e.g.,

```
>> cellfun(@str2double,x,"UniformOutput", false)
ans =
{
  [1,1] = 23
  [1,2] = 3
  [1,3] = NaN
}
```

or another option (thank @Luis Mendo)

```
>> num2cell(str2double(x))
ans =
{
  [1,1] = 23
  [1,2] = 3
  [1,3] = NaN
}
```

Comment: @ThomasIsCoding Ah, I hadn't noticed that the result has to be a cell array